# Display category on menu only when post(s) assigned in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm implementing a wordpress website and there are lot of categories has been created on admin panel. But I don't want to display the categories in the menu which does not have any post assigned to them.

Is it possible to add a bit of code to hide the categories in the menu that don't have posts assigned to them? If yes, could anybody help me to get the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shoud post some code showing what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Category Posts in Custom Menu" this wordpress extension helped me to get the solution

Link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts-in-custom-menu/

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correct you are trying to do something like this:

```
$args = array(
'hide_empty' => 1,
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

**hide_empty** will hide categories that has no posts attached to them.